# eager nested loading with hasOne relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have appointments with relation to contract as `hasOne`

```
public function contract()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Contract', 'appointment_id', 'MAppointments');
}
```

I am using VUE so need use eager loader to get all relations for all appointments for user

```
$appointments = Appointment::with('contract.status')->where('MUser_id', $request->userId)->get();
```

How can i add another conditions to hasOne?
What i tried and not working

```
public function contract()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Contract', 'appointment_id', 'MAppointments')->where('user_id', 'MUser_id);
}
```

and

```
$appointments = Appointment::with('contract.status')->where('MUser_id', $request->userId)->get();
```

```
$appointments = Appointment::with([
    'contract' => function($query) use($request) {
         query->where('user_id', $request->userId);
     },
     'status',
])->where('MUser_id', $request->userId)->get();
```

Is any way to achieve this?

Comment: what is "not working"? what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use MUser_id

```
public function contract()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Contract', 'appointment_id', 'MAppointments')->where('user_id', $this->MUser_id);
}
```

Also

```
$appointments = Appointment::with([
    'contract' => function($query) use($request) {
         $query->where('user_id', $request->userId);
     },
     'status',
])->where('MUser_id', $request->userId)->get();
```

$query is a variable and you forget to use $ :)